# How do I create a passback tag from a URL?

Tags: javascript, redirect, ads

I have a couple of ad networks that have been able to integrate a passback URL (requested when a paid ad impression is not available) but one ad network can only accept a passback script tag, which I don't have.

The passback script needs to load the contents of a URL (a 728x90 image or flash banner) into itself (it also needs to execute the Javascript that it loads). Can anyone help me construct a passback script tag?

I tried this:

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">

// loads within itself, in the 728x90 banner space

document.write("<SCR"+"IPT language=\'Javascript\' src=\'http://www.mydomain.com/passback.php\'></SCR"+"IPT>");

</SCRIPT>
```

But got script errors. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tom How does the `passback.js` file look like?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Your code (the part you've shown) is fine. It's the script pointed in *src* attribute that causes the problems - care to share it? Also, following Jan question - what script errors are you getting?

Comment: does `passback.php` have the correct MIME type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just an idea. What does it give if you try this ?

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";  // This is for HTML 4.01 validation
script.src = "http://www.mydomain.com/passback.php";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: you aren't getting the error from the code above, it's elsewhere

Comment: I agree with @alessioalex, this error is likely in your script itself. Try validating your javascript in something like jslint to try and find missing semicolons and curly braces. I also upvoted the above answer as this is a good technique.

Comment: I, too, agree with @alessioalex .

Comment: It's clear that errors author is getting aren't caused by his `document.write...` code - so why bothering rewriting that part? It's the script linked in *src* (or other potential scripts on page) that is causing the errors to pop-out.

Comment: The script that's being loaded is an Adsense tag, and the script error occurs when the Adsense tag tries to link to it's own external script.

Comment: Then I suggest you to change the "advertising" tag to "adsense", to attract more Google Adsense specialists. There could be an encoding problem.

Comment: The solution was to just use an iframe. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The script already provided is close to the one I always use for this:

```
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = "//www.mydomain.com/passback.php";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
```

The only thing that is different is that the URL scheme is not specified therefore if you are running on an http server then the http url will be called and if you run on https then https will be called - mixing them would be  reason that you scripts may not load.

With your script error I would suggest using Chrome and the developer tools - this would allow you to see exactly which line is giving you that error.

Comment: +1 Especially for not having `http:||https:`. Why do people ever add that?

Comment: @Josh specifying the URL scheme is the "correct" way from a standards perspective. The scheme-less url is really more of a hack that takes advantage of the fact that all browsers fall back to the current page scheme when unsure what to use (a recent discovery). That said I DO USE and advocate scheme-less urls, but also acknowledge where the standards came from. Now that scheme-less URLs are so prevalent and useful, they may become standard. But the original intention was for all URLs to have a scheme. The list of schemes is much longer than just http/https and urls can be used outside the web.

Comment: I'm aware of other schemes, but this question is in the browser, so would anyone subject theirself to the errors caused by attemting to access `http` from an `https` scheme?

Answer (score 0):

The following function loads another document into document body. The URL of the new document should be in the same domain which is *http://www.mydomain.com/* in your case.

You need to save the following script as a .js file and put it where the ad should be placed.

```
function load(url) {
    var req = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { //fallback
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    }

    if (req) {
        req.open("GET", url, false);
        req.send(null);
        return req.responseText;
    }
}

document.write(load("http://www.mydomain.com/passback.php"));
```